# vroom-express and ors , locations out of bounds

Tags: openrouteservice, vroom

hey have trouble getting the locations to work no idea how

this is my api request :

http://localhost:3000

header Content-Type application/json

and body :

{"vehicles":[{"id":1,"profile":"driving-car","start":[54.709692, 25.272143], "end":[54.709692, 25.272143]}],"jobs":[{"id": 179,"location":[54.693050, 25.269890]},{"id": 178,"location":[54.683740, 25.289531]},{"id": 182,"location":[54.685166, 25.293319]},{"id": 181,"location":[54.685856, 25.281992]},{"id": 183,"location":[54.681682, 25.292441]},{"id": 185,"location":[54.676300, 25.292420]},{"id": 186,"location":[54.684549, 25.277140]},{"id": 187,"location":[54.677009, 25.285071]},{"id": 189,"location":[54.684012, 25.288001]},{"id": 190,"location":[54.679161, 25.287042]},{"id": 191,"location":[54.675749, 25.288050]},{"id": 194,"location":[54.680044, 25.280552]},{"id": 195,"location":[54.676440, 25.286386]},{"id": 193,"location":[54.683943, 25.279566]},{"id": 176,"location":[54.687952, 25.276155]},{"id": 180,"location":[54.592051, 25.057288]},{"id": 192,"location":[54.682603, 25.281333]},{"id": 177,"location":[54.680198, 25.282857]}]}

the response i get is :

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "error": "Source point(s) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] out of bounds: 25.272143,54.709692; 25.26989,54.69305; 25.289531,54.68374; 25.293319,54.685166; 25.281992,54.685856; 25.292441,54.681682; 25.29242,54.6763; 25.27714,54.684549; 25.285071,54.677009; 25.288001,54.684012; 25.287042,54.679161; 25.28805,54.675749; 25.280552,54.680044; 25.286386,54.67644; 25.279566,54.683943; 25.276155,54.687952; 25.057288,54.592051; 25.281333,54.682603; 25.282857,54.680198. Destination point(s) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18] out of bounds: 25.272143,54.709692; 25.26989,54.69305; 25.289531,54.68374; 25.293319,54.685166; 25.281992,54.685856; 25.292441,54.681682; 25.29242,54.6763; 25.27714,54.684549; 25.285071,54.677009; 25.288001,54.684012; 25.287042,54.679161; 25.28805,54.675749; 25.280552,54.680044; 25.286386,54.67644; 25.279566,54.683943; 25.276155,54.687952; 25.057288,54.592051; 25.281333,54.682603; 25.282857,54.680198"
}
```

my ors docker-compose.yml file is :

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  ors-app:
    container_name: ors-app
    ports:
      - "3006:8080"
      - "9001:9001"
    image: openrouteservice/openrouteservice:latest
    user: "${UID:-0}:${GID:-0}"
#    build:
#      context: ../
#      args:
#        ORS_CONFIG: ./openrouteservice/src/main/resources/ors-config-sample.json
#        OSM_FILE: ./openrouteservice/src/main/files/heidelberg.osm.gz
    volumes:
      - ./graphs:/home/ors/ors-core/data/graphs
      - ./elevation_cache:/home/ors/ors-core/data/elevation_cache
      - ./logs/ors:/home/ors/ors-core/logs/ors
      - ./logs/tomcat:/home/ors/tomcat/logs
      - ./conf:/home/ors/ors-conf
      - /Users/danieliuskalinin/Downloads/lithuania-latest.osm.pbf
    environment:
      - BUILD_GRAPHS=False  # Forces the container to rebuild the graphs, e.g. when PBF is changed
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=75 -XX:SurvivorRatio=64 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=3 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Xms1g -Xmx2g"
      - "CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

ive tried multiple times to download new map and i keep getting the same error. whats the problem ? im need working with vroom-express and ors